# ERROR: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL

Tags: c++, linux

I keep receiving same error after compilation my CodeWars code. Tried to handle with all warnings and though after that it keeps popping up anyway.I checked the same questions and some of them had been resolved by manipulating with boundaries or memory allocation. But, here, i can't understand where the actual error lies in the code.

Here is my code:

```
   #include <vector>
    #include <numeric>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    
    int maxSequence(const vector<int>& arr)
    {   
        vector <unsigned long> temp2;
        vector <unsigned long> temp1;
        int result,sum_max = 0;
        for(unsigned long i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i)
        {
            sum_max = arr[i];
            for(unsigned long j = i+1; j < arr.size(); ++j)
            {
                sum_max += arr[j];
                temp1.push_back(sum_max);
            }
            result = *max_element(temp1.begin(), temp1.end());
            temp1.clear();
            temp2.push_back(result);
        }
    
        result = *max_element(temp2.begin(),temp2.end());
        return result;
    }
```

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GohCH.png)
[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK0el.png)

```
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
==1==ERROR: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x000000425881 bp 0x7ffe7abb2300 sp 0x7ffe7abb1e10 T1)
==1==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==1==Hint: address points to the zero page.
==1==WARNING: invalid path to external symbolizer!
==1==WARNING: Failed to use and restart external symbolizer!
    #0 0x425880  (/workspace/test+0x425880)
    #1 0x4282de  (/workspace/test+0x4282de)
    #2 0x426a6e  (/workspace/test+0x426a6e)
    #3 0x4265e9  (/workspace/test+0x4265e9)
    #4 0x42622b  (/workspace/test+0x42622b)
    #5 0x42aa55  (/workspace/test+0x42aa55)
    #6 0x42599d  (/workspace/test+0x42599d)
    #7 0x7f9e4fd4ebf6  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21bf6)
    #8 0x404519  (/workspace/test+0x404519)

UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer can not provide additional info.
==1==ABORTING
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] so we can run this code. Address sanitizer finds some null pointer was dereferenced.

Comment: Think about how many elements there are in `temp1` when `i` is `arr.size() - 2` or greater.

Comment: what does `*max_element(temp1.begin(), temp1.end())` do if `temp1` is empty?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I added to the code: if(!temp1.empty()){....} but it keeps showing this error message... Anyway , thanks for the advice, i did't notice it

Comment: The same applies to `*max_element(temp2.begin(),temp2.end())`...

Comment: @AlanBirtles , i figured out what the problem  was : i had to add one more extra statement in case input vector were empty. But now: another problem occured :) It's about built-in function max_element() which normally should return the pointer to the maximum element, but, when i print it on my computer, it shows 6 (as it should be). But , when trying to submit it , error tells that it returns -1 instead of 6. I assume that it belongs to this function max_element. The problem lies somewhere there. Smt with return statement as pointer...

Comment: If you've solved your own problem feel free to add an answer. Your new problem sounds like a new question (be sure to add a [mre] if you do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i tried to submit my code without checking all required conditions. So,I had to add if-statement in case input vector is empty.

```
if (arr.size() == 0){return 0;} or if(arr.empty()){return 0;}
```